Metaplex Core - Owner can revoke transfer delegate of an asset on escrowless sale
I am trying to make an anchor escrowless sale of a metaplex core asset. For this, I first freeze the asset and then add a transfer delegate, I set the authority to the program on both plugins. The idea is that when the sale is over, the owner, the buyer, or the program can complete the sale by transferring the asset and the funds. Since the program is the transfer delegate, this should be possible.
However, I did some tests, and even if the asset is frozen, and the transfer delegate authority is set to some address (the program in this case), the transfer delegate can be revoked at any point by the owner. So the only actor that can complete the sale is the owner with the frozen asset, and if the owner never completes it then the buyer will not get his asset.
Here is some code to replicate the behavior:
    // Create asset args
    const assetSigner = generateSigner(umi)
    const collection = await fetchCollection(umi, collectionSigner.publicKey);
    const assetArgs = {
        collection: collection,
        asset: assetSigner,
        name: 'My asset',
        uri: "",
    };

    // Create asset
    await create(umi, assetArgs).sendAndConfirm(umi);
    let asset = await fetchAsset(umi, assetSigner.publicKey)
    console.log("--- 0. Asset created ---")
    console.log(asset)

    // add transfer delegate
    const transferDelegate = generateSigner(umi)
    const addTransferDelegateArgs: AddPluginArgs =  {
        asset: asset.publicKey,
        collection: collection.publicKey,
        plugin: {
            type: "TransferDelegate",
            authority: { 
                type: 'Address', 
                address: transferDelegate.publicKey
            },
        },
    };
    await addPlugin(umi, addTransferDelegateArgs).sendAndConfirm(umi)
    asset = await fetchAsset(umi, assetSigner.publicKey)
    console.log("--- 1. Transfer authorithy added---")
    console.log(`Transfer authority ${transferDelegate.publicKey}`)
    console.log(asset)

    // freeze asset
    const freezeAssetArgs = {
        asset: asset,
        collection: collection,
        delegate: transferDelegate.publicKey
    };
    await freezeAsset(umi, freezeAssetArgs).sendAndConfirm(umi);
    asset = await fetchAsset(umi, assetSigner.publicKey)
    console.log("--- 2. Asset frozen ---")
    console.log(`Freeze authority ${transferDelegate.publicKey}`)
    console.log(asset)

    // remove transfer delegate
    const revokeTransferDelegateArgs: RevokePluginAuthorityArgs = {
        asset: asset.publicKey,
        collection: collection.publicKey,
        authority: signer, // the owner
        plugin: { type: "TransferDelegate" },
        
    }
    await revokePluginAuthority(umi, revokeTransferDelegateArgs).sendAndConfirm(umi)
    asset = await fetchAsset(umi, assetSigner.publicKey)
    console.log("--- 3. Revoked Transfer Delegate ---")
    console.log(asset)

    // update transfer delegate authority
    const transferDelegate2 = generateSigner(umi)
    const approvePluginAuthorityArgs: ApprovePluginAuthorityArgs = {
        asset: asset.publicKey,
        collection: collection.publicKey,
        authority: signer, // the owner
        newAuthority: { type: 'Address', address: transferDelegate2.publicKey},
        plugin: { type: "TransferDelegate" },
    };
    await approvePluginAuthority(umi, approvePluginAuthorityArgs).sendAndConfirm(umi)
    asset = await fetchAsset(umi, assetSigner.publicKey)
    console.log("--- 4. New transfer delegate ---")
    console.log(`New transfer authority ${transferDelegate2.publicKey}`)
    console.log(asset)

This succeeds, so I'm not sure how to do the escrowless sale. I append some logs to check it:
--- 0. Asset created ---
{
  publicKey: 'QFM3oKCWerHjEK7QMn1vvPoxNBybrW3WV4RfsDiFf2b',
  header: {
    executable: false,
    owner: 'CoREENxT6tW1HoK8ypY1SxRMZTcVPm7R94rH4PZNhX7d',
    lamports: { basisPoints: 2968560n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    rentEpoch: 18446744073709551616n,
    exists: true
  },
  pluginHeader: undefined,
  key: 1,
  updateAuthority: {
    type: 'Collection',
    address: 'FJk1tYuJD96EgJ7odHj76CFzgQ8UoRHdTKQpYGeGRHyp'
  },
  name: 'My asset',
  uri: '',
  owner: '3YwBqTFLrKP48GkA5bWdeYXnMK8txgDPcYvaA5rRzfJh',
  seq: { __option: 'None' }
}
--- 1. Transfer authorithy added---
Transfer authority ffGTDYh8PVQocYnLNmxS8BTgYUc6FwunzvV55n7DYfE
{
  publicKey: 'QFM3oKCWerHjEK7QMn1vvPoxNBybrW3WV4RfsDiFf2b',
  header: {
    executable: false,
    owner: 'CoREENxT6tW1HoK8ypY1SxRMZTcVPm7R94rH4PZNhX7d',
    lamports: { basisPoints: 3393120n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    rentEpoch: 18446744073709551616n,
    exists: true
  },
  pluginHeader: { key: 3, pluginRegistryOffset: 93n },
  key: 1,
  updateAuthority: {
    type: 'Collection',
    address: 'FJk1tYuJD96EgJ7odHj76CFzgQ8UoRHdTKQpYGeGRHyp'
  },
  name: 'My asset',
  uri: '',
  transferDelegate: {
    authority: {
      type: 'Address',
      address: 'ffGTDYh8PVQocYnLNmxS8BTgYUc6FwunzvV55n7DYfE'
    },
    offset: 92n
  },
  owner: '3YwBqTFLrKP48GkA5bWdeYXnMK8txgDPcYvaA5rRzfJh',
  seq: { __option: 'None' }
}
--- 2. Asset frozen ---
Freeze authority ffGTDYh8PVQocYnLNmxS8BTgYUc6FwunzvV55n7DYfE
{
  publicKey: 'QFM3oKCWerHjEK7QMn1vvPoxNBybrW3WV4RfsDiFf2b',
  header: {
    executable: false,
    owner: 'CoREENxT6tW1HoK8ypY1SxRMZTcVPm7R94rH4PZNhX7d',
    lamports: { basisPoints: 3699360n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    rentEpoch: 18446744073709551616n,
    exists: true
  },
  pluginHeader: { key: 3, pluginRegistryOffset: 95n },
  key: 1,
  updateAuthority: {
    type: 'Collection',
    address: 'FJk1tYuJD96EgJ7odHj76CFzgQ8UoRHdTKQpYGeGRHyp'
  },
  name: 'My asset',
  uri: '',
  transferDelegate: {
    authority: {
      type: 'Address',
      address: 'ffGTDYh8PVQocYnLNmxS8BTgYUc6FwunzvV55n7DYfE'
    },
    offset: 92n
  },
  freezeDelegate: {
    authority: {
      type: 'Address',
      address: 'ffGTDYh8PVQocYnLNmxS8BTgYUc6FwunzvV55n7DYfE'
    },
    offset: 93n,
    frozen: true
  },
  owner: '3YwBqTFLrKP48GkA5bWdeYXnMK8txgDPcYvaA5rRzfJh',
  seq: { __option: 'None' }
}
--- 3. Revoked Transfer Delegate ---
{
  publicKey: 'QFM3oKCWerHjEK7QMn1vvPoxNBybrW3WV4RfsDiFf2b',
  header: {
    executable: false,
    owner: 'CoREENxT6tW1HoK8ypY1SxRMZTcVPm7R94rH4PZNhX7d',
    lamports: { basisPoints: 3476640n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    rentEpoch: 18446744073709551616n,
    exists: true
  },
  pluginHeader: { key: 3, pluginRegistryOffset: 95n },
  key: 1,
  updateAuthority: {
    type: 'Collection',
    address: 'FJk1tYuJD96EgJ7odHj76CFzgQ8UoRHdTKQpYGeGRHyp'
  },
  name: 'My asset',
  uri: '',
  transferDelegate: { authority: { type: 'Owner', address: undefined }, offset: 92n },
  freezeDelegate: {
    authority: {
      type: 'Address',
      address: 'ffGTDYh8PVQocYnLNmxS8BTgYUc6FwunzvV55n7DYfE'
    },
    offset: 93n,
    frozen: true
  },
  owner: '3YwBqTFLrKP48GkA5bWdeYXnMK8txgDPcYvaA5rRzfJh',
  seq: { __option: 'None' }
}
--- 4. New transfer delegate ---
New transfer authority 3q4FxXCDghymL5ndzSGebLrh2hwVXBP71vFUX2MseYS8
{
  publicKey: 'QFM3oKCWerHjEK7QMn1vvPoxNBybrW3WV4RfsDiFf2b',
  header: {
    executable: false,
    owner: 'CoREENxT6tW1HoK8ypY1SxRMZTcVPm7R94rH4PZNhX7d',
    lamports: { basisPoints: 3706320n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    rentEpoch: 18446744073709551616n,
    exists: true
  },
  pluginHeader: { key: 3, pluginRegistryOffset: 95n },
  key: 1,
  updateAuthority: {
    type: 'Collection',
    address: 'FJk1tYuJD96EgJ7odHj76CFzgQ8UoRHdTKQpYGeGRHyp'
  },
  name: 'My asset',
  uri: '',
  transferDelegate: {
    authority: {
      type: 'Address',
      address: '3q4FxXCDghymL5ndzSGebLrh2hwVXBP71vFUX2MseYS8'
    },
    offset: 92n
  },
  freezeDelegate: {
    authority: {
      type: 'Address',
      address: 'ffGTDYh8PVQocYnLNmxS8BTgYUc6FwunzvV55n7DYfE'
    },
    offset: 93n,
    frozen: true
  },
  owner: '3YwBqTFLrKP48GkA5bWdeYXnMK8txgDPcYvaA5rRzfJh',
  seq: { __option: 'None' }
}

I would appreciate any help/advice. Thanks.
